# vba : Can't seem to turn off the "making unconstrained variables non-negative" option for Solver

Tags: vba, setting

After
    SolverReset

I want to switch off the Make Unconstrained Variables Non-Negative option in the vba Solver.

What are the commands to switch off the Make Unconstrained Variables Non-Negative in Solver?

I tried recording a macro to find out but all I got was,

```
Sub Macro2()
'
' Macro2 Macro
'

'
    SolverOk SetCell:="$D$26", MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$B$9:$B$12", _
        Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
    SolverOk SetCell:="$D$26", MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$B$9:$B$12", _
        Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
    SolverSolve
End Sub
```

Answer (score 9):

What you want to do is add:

```
SolverOptions Assumenonneg:=False
```

The full details of all solver options can be found on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195446(v=office.15).aspx).

Answer (score 2):

When you record a 'SOLVER' macro, open the options tab in the SOLVER window and then close. Click SOLVE and then 'stop-recording' This should give the 'SLOVER options" as below. The option that you need is AssumeNonNeg:= False (or True) as required

```
SolverOptions MaxTime:=0, Iterations:=0, Precision:=0.000001, Convergence:= _
        0.0001, StepThru:=False, Scaling:=True, AssumeNonNeg:=False, Derivatives:=1
    SolverOptions PopulationSize:=100, RandomSeed:=0, MutationRate:=0.075, Multistart _
        :=False, RequireBounds:=True, MaxSubproblems:=0, MaxIntegerSols:=0, _
        IntTolerance:=1, SolveWithout:=False, MaxTimeNoImp:=30
```